# Searching for a multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, flash, upload

I'm looking for a multiple file upload button. the ones I've found are

- swfupload
- uploadify
- and a jquery plugin: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

I want to integrate it in a django app. ATM the only one which is working without any problems and is in widespread use seems to be swfupload.

Am I right or am I missing another one?

Answer (score 0):

SWFUpload is the way to go.  I've used it in several apps and has the best features out of any of them.